# Gitlab error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden

Tags: git, gitlab, plesk

I have installed recently Gitlab on my dedicated server and everything was fine until today. I have to say I'm using Gitlab on a Plesk apache webhost; I used that tutorial to do this: https://www.jonasjuffinger.com/2017/03/26/gitlab-with-plesk-and-lets-encrypt/

Like said, everything was fine and suddenly, I got the RPC failed 403 error in the title when I'm pushing to any repository from my local.

I tried many solutions and passed all the day looking what's wrong with no luck at all...

I'm up to give any additional informations when required on that topic.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed location problem looking every logs of gitlab & more successfully plesk / apache ones.
The problem was "mod_security" in Apache that was blocking certain types of connection.

Results was:
- This RPC 403 Forbidden error
- Impossibility to enable, delete Deploy Keys
- (Maybe other problems I didn't noticed)

So it's now all resolved. Hope this can help.